# hashCode method in case equals method supports wildchar

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a class, whose objects will be stored in hashmap, hashset.

I need to support wildchar equality for the fields therefore I have added that check in `equals` method. Now, how can I build my hashcode method based on this paramter? i.e. if I calculate as shown in code below, I will get different hashcode for 2 objects that pass the equality check of my equals method.

For e.g. consider following class:

```
public class Person {   

    private String fname = "";
    private String lname = "";
    private String profession = "";

    // getters & setters



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (fname == null) {
            if (other.fname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!fname.equals(other.fname) && !other.fname.equals("*") && !fname.equals("*"))
            return false;
        return true;

        // similar for other fields
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {     
        return Objects.hashCode(this.fname, this.lname , this.profession);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in some of the comments that there should be a separate method to check wildchar equality. The limitation with this approach is I won't be able to get the correct results for methods like `set.contains` as they check for `object.equals` internally. So my `set.contains` will return false, even if my objects passes the equality test of my separate wildchar equality method.

Comment: You need to customize hash-code based on that.. Generate default hash-code method from any of the ides and customize it based on your logic.

Comment: that is a very weird equals imlementation, I must say.. especially since it won't even compile, can you show us your actual attempt?

Comment: "The limitation with this approach is..." The limitation in *your* approach is that it violates the formal requirements on the equals and hashCode methods, and thus you should have no expectation of correct functioning when using data structures and algorithms which rely on them.

Comment: The `.equals` method *must* be transitive (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Hence, if you want  `"a".equals("*")` to return true and `"*".equals ("b")` to return true, then you *must* return true with `"a".equals ("b")`.

Comment: Are you creating something like `persons.contains(new Person("*", "myLastName", "myProfession"))` to check if there is one more persons with `"myLastName"` and `"myProfession"` regardelss of the first name? Why not stream over `persons` and check if `persons.stream().anyMatch(p-> p.getLname().equals("myLastName") && p.getProfession().endsWith("myProfession"));` (omitted null checks for readability)

Comment: @LuCio Your understanding is right of what I am trying to do. The above example shows limited fields. However my actual implementation has more fields and of multiple types. But I can think along those lines.

Comment: @tryingToLearn Actually you are giving `anyMatch` a `Predicate`. You can define a `Predicate` which will evaluate more fields of a `Person`.

Comment: EDIT for my comment above. The last part should be: `&& p.getProfession().equals(profession));`  (but that's probably obvious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same logic in `hashCode()` is not possible as **we don't compute the hash code according to a compared object but we compute it according to the current object state**.
You could return a constant value in the `hashCode()` method but it would be not efficient and so it doesn't sound a good idea.
Your original issue comes from the fact that you want to give a responsibility not designed to be into the `equals()` method : defining the equality beyond the actual state of the objects (that is actual field values).
So you should not use the `equals()` method to perform the wildcard comparison but instead of write a dedicated method for.

Comment: I understand that but the limitation with this approach is I won't be able to get the correct results for methods like `set.contains` as they check for `object.equals` internally. So my `set.contains` will return false, even if my objects passes the equality test of my separate method.

Comment: If performance is not a matter as said you may return a constant in `hashCode()` and so it will work in any case but you will lose the fastness of a hash table. Sorry but with such a requirement, unfortunately you are in a corner.

Comment: And is there no way that you can use a different method than `contains`? The problem is one of design: `"a"` does not equal `"*"`, even though it matches. Similarly, your set does not contain that value. Can you make a derived version of the set where you override the `contains` method, even in-place if needs be?

Comment: An `equals` method using wildcards violates the *transitivity* rule, i.e. when `a` is equal to `*` and `*` is equal to `b`, then `a` must be equal to `b`. All collection implementations rely on correct `equals` implementations and may exhibit the strangest behaviors if you violate the rules.